# Is it possible to configure multiple Graphite endpoints for one neo4j host

Tags: neo4j, graphite

I want a highly available way to monitor our neo4j cluster in Graphite, but it is unclear from https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.2/monitoring/metrics/ whether or not multiple graphite endpoints can be configured for one neo4j host.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nop it's not possible, so you need to do it on the graphite stack side.

There are some features on carbon to do it, like configure it as a proxy and to push metrics to a graphite cluster (but I'm not a specialist on this topic)